# Seeking instructions to finish partially assembled custom Lego satellite (Orbital Science Corporation)

Tags: sets, instructions

This week I found a partially assembled Lego satellite and I wanted to build it but I can't find the instructions to finish it. The satellite I'm 90% sure is a scale model from a satellite launched by Orbital Science Corporation, but I don't know which one.

My father gifted me this set in 2012 (I don't have the exact date). My father got the set from one of his friends that worked in Orbital Science Corporation at the time. According to my father the satellite can be the Koreansat6 or the Indostar-1 or the Measat 3a. If anyone happens to have the set or the instructions to it please reply, I'm desperate.

I will leave some images of the only assembled parts I have:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/28ZZD.jpg

Comment: The size of clear film used for "Orbital" stickers suggest me this is a custom set or MOC. The most recent appearance of Black Panel 3 x 3 x 6 Corner Wall used here is 1995 set.

Comment: I meant to say, that panel seen in your pictures was last included in 1995 as seen on [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2345&colorID=11&in=A).

Comment: Hi Nico! I have searched for all three suggested satellite names, but found no relevant results. There is an unofficial Measat 3a model out there, but it is an entirely different scale and thus uses different parts: http://ericdeteh.blogspot.com/2015/12/measat-3b-satellite.html Long story short, I couldn't find your model either.

Comment: @Alex, thanks for looking into into, lets hope we can find something else.

Comment: @zovits Thanks for looking into it, I coudnt even find that set so its some progress.